# How do I merge multiple dates backup from Time Machine?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I can't seem to find an answer for my question regarding this subject. Pardon my ignorance, but I have an External hard drive which I use as drive for my Time Machine backups and I realized that Time Machine makes multiple backups, but there's a lot of duplicated files (as it organizes by dates).
Is there a way to compile or merge all the backups in just one?
I'm sorry if that's a dumb question, but I don't know a lot regarding this subject and would be very greatfull if someone can help me with that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it.

Time Machine handles all this itself without any user intervention. It keeps several backups per day, then one a week, then one a month… right back to the start of the backup.

It does this without using *any* extra disk space, but making hard links to any files which appear to be duplicated. This means that there is really only one file, but many places you can see it.

Comment: Oh, now I understand! Thanks for clarifiying that for me!